# Drivers for ASUS mid-audio 892

Tags: 14.04, sound

I'm running 14.04. I installed an ASUS mid-audio 892 card that's supposed to be supported, but the system just won't see it. I found drivers for Red Hat, etc., but not for Ubuntu/debian.  Help?  Thanks.  CC

Comment: Is it a notebook or pci-card in a desktop-PC ?

Answer (score 0):

Though am deaf to sound on any devices in the world here, I know how this works on Ubuntu. This is because of missing libraries:

Easy work-around can work it out:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install synaptic (the debian-package manager with enough packages)
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall amarok rhythmbox --fix-missing
>
> sudo reboot

In case still no sound you should not be frightened by upgrade-suggestion to Ubuntu 15.04.03 (LTS3) only when there is a window popping up, but this is not a must. Only if wished and if necessary then do in the end :

> sudo apt-get install dist-upgrade (takes longer time)

In case of still-no-sound ... let me know, and I adjust this thread.